# WPF ListView with external scrollbar and remove color overlay

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, styles, scrollviewer

I have XAML looking like this

```
<ScrollViewer>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ListViewer>
    ...
    </ListViewer>

    <ListViewer>
    ...
    </ListViewer>
  </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Question 1.
How can I make sure the scrolling is completely handled by the outermost scrollviewer? If I scroll now with the mouse wheel in any of the listview controls there won't be any scrolling occuring. If I scroll somewhere just outside of the ListViews the scrolling works as expected.

Question 2.
How can I get rid of the highlight "mouse over" and "selected" color overlay from the ListViews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `PreviewMouseWheel` event handler to manually handle the scrolling. Also, replace the `ContentTemplate` of the `ListViewItem` to customize its look (namely, remove the selection and mouse-over highlighting):

```
<ScrollViewer PreviewMouseWheel="OnPreviewMouseWheel">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                <Border Padding="4,2">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Here's the event handler:

```
private void OnPreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)sender;
    scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer.VerticalOffset - e.Delta);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Your `ListView` is starting to look like a simple `ItemsControl`, so consider using that instead (although the `ItemsControl` doesn't come with its own scrolling behavior).

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm!
You wrote I could change ListView to ItemsControl. Do I just need to change that or are there more stuff I would have to change then?
I should mention I have <ListView.ItemTemplate> would that just be <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> then. Is there any pros of why I would use an ItemsControl over a ListView control?
Again thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, just replace `ListView` with `ItemsControl`. You won't need to handle scrolling or remove the highlighting. As you said, you'll just need to use `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate`. The main pro is that it's a simpler structure that may fit perfectly with what you want to do.